# parsing a list of columns to a pandas dataframe to show only those columns

Tags: python, pandas

I know with pandas if you have a dataframe (df) you can get columns using df.columns.values to return an object (not sure of which type) but you can convert this to a string.

If my dataframe has 10 columns and I know the names of the first three can I create a string, and parse it to the dataframe to show only those columns?

```
subset_columns['one','two','three']
df[[subset_colimns]]
```

> ```
> df OUT >>
> ```

```
one | two | three
1345 415    1654
13445 56576  76r76
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the columns to a list either by casting or using the numpy `tolist()` function. You can then select from this by slicing in the normal manner:

```
In [5]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list('abcdefghij'), [arange(10)] * 10)))
cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
# you can also do list(df.columns)

In [11]:
cols

Out[11]:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

In [12]:
subcols = cols[2:5]
df[subcols]

Out[12]:
   c  d  e
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5
6  6  6  6
7  7  7  7
8  8  8  8
9  9  9  9

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

In order to select multiple non-sequential columns you can do this:

```
In [36]
part1 = cols[0:3]
part2 = cols[6:8]
subcols = part1+part2
df[subcols]

Out[36]:

   a  b  c  g  h
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5  5  5
6  6  6  6  6  6
7  7  7  7  7  7
8  8  8  8  8  8
9  9  9  9  9  9

[10 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: can you slice from your list i-j and say I want the firs four, then skip the next 2, then give me 3 more?

so a,b,c,d,g,h?

Comment: @yoshiserry not concisely you would have to do something like `part1 = cols[0:3], part2 = cols[6:8], subcols = part1+part2, df[subcols]`

Comment: for some reason when I do that (parse a subset of columns) it combines the index and the first column 'Load year' together, how do I stop this?

Comment: @yoshiserry that shouldn't happen can you post another question including code and data that reproduces the error and I can have a look

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can select required columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv("../SO/data.csv")
df.head()
    card_number effective_date  expiry_date grouping_name   Ac. Year code
0    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.1  201213
1    1206090     21 Feb 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.2  201213
2    1206090     28 Sep 2012     30 Nov 2012     Dummy no.3  201213
3    1206090     03 Dec 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.3  201213
4    1206090     23 Apr 2013     31 Aug 2013     Dummy no.4  201213
```

req_cols is list of required columns below:

```
req_cols = ['card_number', 'expiry_date', 'grouping_name']
df[req_cols].head()

    card_number expiry_date grouping_name
0    1206090     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.1
1    1206090     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.2
2    1206090     30 Nov 2012     Dummy no.3
3    1206090     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.3
4    1206090     31 Aug 2013     Dummy no.4
```